# How do I generate a random number between an inputted range using the mod operator?

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how to generate a number between a range predefined by the user using the mod operator.

What I do not want

```
int min = input.nextInt();
int max = input.nextInt();

Random r = new Random();
int X = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
```

What I want, something akin to a traditional int X = gen.nextInt() % 100 + 1; but instead using values for Max and Min.

Here is what I have so far

```
import java.util.*;

public class Modulus
{// begin class
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {// begin  main
    Scanner input;
    int max, min, range;
    Random gen;

    gen = new Random();


    input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a max value: ");
    max = input.nextInt();
    // Ask user to input max value

    System.out.println(" Please enter a minimum value: ");
    min = input.nextInt();
    // Ask user to input min value

     range = gen.nextInt() % (Unknown) 
    // Get random integer between min and max values using %


    System.out.println(" Your generated number is: " + range );






    } 
//end main
}
//end class
```

Can anyone explain how I might be able to accomplish this using the mod operator?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648976/random-number-generator

Comment: @Jason No, that isn't a duplicate.  The linked question doesn't use `Random` at all and appears to be about trying to `write` a very simple random number generator.

Comment: @Aztechnology to get range between 0 - 100 using your formular  int X = random.nextInt(100 - 0 + 1) + 0; its thesame as nextInt(101) so whats the point ? thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Math.abs()` function.

ie

```
public static int genRandom(int mod){
  Random r = new Random();
  return Math.abs(r.nextInt()) % mod + 1;
}
```

and plug your high number as a parameter.  The caveat to this is it works only with non-negative values.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to work with negative  values as well :\. Thank you anyways!

Comment: This will fail if `nextInt()` happens to return `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: @ajb, that's true, but implementing a conditional re-generation of the number is trivial to implement.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
 range = Math.abs(gen.nextInt() % (max - min + 1)) + min
```

will get what you want.  The `%` operator returns a value from `0` to `max-min` if `nextInt` returns a positive number or 0, or from `0` to `-(max-min)` if `nextInt` returns a negative.  So `abs` will return a number in the range `0` to `max-min`, and adding `min` gets you a number in the range `min` to `max`.

I don't recommend doing it this way, though.  When you generate a random integer from a set of M integers, and then use `%` to reduce it to a set of N integers, the resulting distribution will not be uniform if M is not divisible by N.  Some results will show up more often than others.  I'm not sure why you don't want to use `gen.nextInt(max - min + 1)`, but it's the right tool for the job.

**EDIT:** The right way to do something like this would be: if you have a way to generate a random number in the range 0 to M-1 inclusive, and you need one in the range 0 to N-1 inclusive, then you need to pick only numbers in the range 0 to N*(M/N)-1 [where M/N is an integer division that truncates], and if the generator picks a number in the range N*(M/N) to M-1, loop back and try again.  Then when you use the `% N` operator on the result you will get a uniform distribution.  (This algorithm has to be adjusted if the generator can generate negative values.)  The code for `Random.nextInt(int n)` does exactly this; here's a comment from the JRE source:

> ```
> * The algorithm is slightly tricky.  It rejects values that would result
> * in an uneven distribution (due to the fact that 2^31 is not divisible
> * by n). The probability of a value being rejected depends on n.  The
> * worst case is n=2^30+1, for which the probability of a reject is 1/2,
> * and the expected number of iterations before the loop terminates is 2.
> ```

So since `nextInt(n)` does the necessary work, the only reason not to use it would be if it's homework and you're not allowed to.

Comment: I actually used a nearly identical code my first time around but was getting numbers outside the range. I'll give it another shot. As to why, it's because it was a bonus question on a test that has been bothering me.